# How to delegate .dragged() attached to child element to the parent?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a parent element and I want to drag it only wehn dragging the title.
I was trying to play with this but with no success..

This is my attempt to solve this problem:
http://jsbin.com/ujOQIZE/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is to use a handle:

```
$('#init-canvas').draggable({
  handle: "header"
});
```

http://jsbin.com/eMERoXo/1/